# Why is laravel migration failing silently?

Tags: php, laravel-4, data-migration

I am converting a 12 year old frameworkless php app into a Laravel app. The old app had two separate user tables which I have merged. Merging them requires massaging the data.  I created a migration to massage the data in one of my tables.

My up() function looks like this:

```
public function up()
{
    $users = User::all();
    foreach($users as $user) {
        if ($user->staff_id = '0') {
            $user->role = '4';
        } elseif ($user->role != '1') {
            $user->role = '3';
        }
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

I had run a similar function in a migration moments previously which ran fine.  However this one produced the following output:

```
myusername at local in ~/Sites/tgdp/trunk
> mamp-php artisan migrate                                                                                                                           
myusername at local in ~/Sites/tgdp/trunk
>
```

And when I looked in my migrations table and at the User table, it was obvious the migration had not been run.

So, to recap.  No error thrown.  No "Nothing to Migrate." No success response.  No effect on the database. *** Edit:** No errors listed in the logs.

Any idea why this might have happened?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you would have any User records at all to pull from during a migration. Have you tried putting it in a seeder instead? How would this run if you deleted your entire database and wanted to re-migrate all of your tables at once?

Comment: Have you checked in the php error log for clues.

Comment: If you have Ardent, or some other "model" validation running, the validation is probably failing, so when you run $user->save() - nothing occurs.

Comment: @watcher Good question.  I am converting a 12 year old frameworkless php app into a Laravel app.  The old app had two separate user tables which I am merging.  Merging them requires massaging the data.  I am doing that data massage in three separate environments and I want to keep the data consistent.  Also, I want to keep data changes stored in version control.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Yep.  No output in the cli logs.

Comment: @vlasits Ok that makes more sense. Glad you found out what your issue was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the problem was that looping through and saving all of those users was very memory intensive.  The solution was to give php limitless access to memory.  Like so:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 artisan migrate
```

Once I did that the code ran fine.